# How to free memory in go?

Tags: go, memory-management, garbage-collection

I've started to learn Go, and found something I'm not able to find info about.

For example, if I'm making my own list structure

```
type elem struct {
    prev  *elem
    next  *elem
    value string
}
```

And adding new elements to it with

```
Current.next = &elem{}
```

How should I remove them? I mean, how can I remove data of elem from memory, not just from the list?

Comment: Go is garbage collected. You don’t do anything other than remove them from your data structure.

Comment: @JimB can you explaing, at what moment, garbage collector will recognize this data in memory as garbage? (didn't get it)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Go has garbage collection. It will scan for data that has no pointer to it and remove it from heap (Garbage collector is running beside your program). The only thing you should do is:

```
Current.next = nil
```

Your `elem{}` will be removed from memory eventually after you remove all pointers to it (It's not deterministic. Can't tell exactly when `elem{}` will be released). There are different implementations of garbage collection; Go's implementation may change at any time.

If `Current` goes out of scope, you don't even need to set `next` to `nil`.

Comment: thanks for the good explanation

Comment: @CrazyWu Your welcome :)

Comment: current.next = nil and current.pre = nil

Comment: @Xiak why? .prev was not set to begin with.